# How do you carry non-circular drilling with an SMD part in gEDA pcb?

Tags: pcb, geda

The recommended pattern for some components might include non circular drilling, like this one:

Here's the pad layout:

[image: Bourns PEC11S encoder]

As per the [datasheet](http://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/PEC11S.pdf) (bottom of page 2), there has to be one circular outline and an oval one for the notches. I'm interested in how you'd carry that along with an SMD component: gEDA pcb footprints don't include an outline layer, just pads, round holes and silk lines and arcs. Is there a standard way other than storing the outline in a separate file — the process which I still need to figure out how to make non-boring...

Carrying a round hole with an SMD component is easy and only requires a pin with flag `0x100` (IIRC). That flag tells the program it is only a drilled hole, non-plated if my memory still serves me right.

Note I still wonder why there has to be an oval hole instead of a round one, which wouldn't cause any trouble at all! The notch doesn't seem to be able to move along, right?

Answer (score 1):

Geda PCB footprints include an outline layer e.g. on a silkscreen layer, if you draw one when you create the footprint. If one of the stock outlines would meet your needs if only it had a footprint, save your own copy of it in e.g. a Footprints folder for your project and make the changes you need.

As regards your oval hole, I would probably substitute a round one drilled to the major diameter, as there is plenty of clearance round it. The part will be a slightly sloppy fit to the PCB as a result, until soldered down.

Otherwise you could make the oval hole at the PCB routing stage, with a suitably small routing bit (it's an unplated hole) but that's an unusual and possibly expensive processing step, PCB fabs don't like that...

The datasheet shows the slotting is only there because Bourns are a little bit coy about the dimension between the two pegs under the part. So a round hole on the minor diameter (1.55mm) at the right dimension would be OK if you knew the right dimension...

My suggested major diameter (2.2mm) hole simply allows the part to rotate right or left by 0.3mm before soldering : decide for yourself if this is acceptable on your board.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. By "outline" I essentially meant the routed (mechanical) layer. gEDA PCB does not inlude that information, only silk screen. So unless I've missed something the latter cannot be taken separately and brought to the outline layer unless I cut the component to the buffer and split it into parts.